# Understanding mutex behviour

Tags: multithreading, go, mutex, goroutine

I was thinking `mutex` in Go would lock the data and won't allow read/write by any other `goroutine` unless the fist `goroutine` releases the lock. It seems like my understanding was wrong. The only way to block read/write from other `goroutine` is to call `lock` in other `goroutines` as well. This would ensure `critical section` is accessed by one and only one `goroutine`.

So, I would expect [this](https://play.golang.org/p/GJujZCtLgUK) code to have a deadlock:

```
package main

import(
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)

type myMap struct {
    m map[string]string
    mutex sync.Mutex
}

func main() {
    done := make(chan bool)
    ch := make(chan bool)
    myM := &myMap{
        m:     make(map[string]string),
    }
    go func() {
        myM.mutex.Lock()
        myM.m["x"] = "i"
        fmt.Println("Locked. Won't release the Lock")
        ch <- true
    }()

    go func() {
        <- ch
        fmt.Println("Trying to write to the myMap")
        myM.m["a"] = "b"
        fmt.Println(myM)
        done <- true
    }()
    <- done
}
```

Since the fist `goroutine` locks the struct, I would expect the second `goroutine` to fail to read/write to the struct but that not happening here.

If I will add `mux.Lock()` in second `goroutine` then there will be a deadlock.

I find it a little weird the way `mutex` works in Go. If I lock then Go shouldn't allow any other `goroutine` to read/write to it.

Can someone explain to me the mutex concept in Go?

Comment: Why do you say the first goroutine "locks the struct" exactly? It locks a mutex, yes. What makes you think that mutex locks the struct as opposed to something else?

Comment: I was thinking that having mutex in a struct lock not just the mutex but the struct itself, it was just my bad understanding.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no magical force field that surrounds a mutex, protecting any datastructure it happens to be embedded in. If you lock a mutex, it prevents other code from locking it until it's unlocked. Nothing more, nothing less. [It's well documented in the `sync` package.](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/#Mutex)

So in your code, where there's exactly one `myM.mutex.Lock()`, the effect is the same as if there was no mutex.

A correct use of a mutex that protects data involves locking the mutex before updating or reading the data, and then unlocking it afterwards. Often this code will be wrapped in a function so that defer can be used:

```
func doSomething(myM *myMap) {
    myM.mutex.Lock()
    defer myM.mutex.Unlock()
    ... read or update myM
}
```

Comment: Got it, but I personally find it confusing.
Anyways, if somewhere in the code missing lock/unlock it will just ruin everything else.

Comment: Yes, synchronization and concurrency require a lot of care otherwise you get deadlocks or just weird stuff happening. The race checker can help, as can good design and encapsulation of your mutable state, but it's not easy at first.

Comment: "if somewhere in the code missing lock/unlock it will just ruin everything else" -- The same can be said of all types of code. If you're missing any code, it can ruin everything. Mutexes are not special in this regard.

Comment: @Mohammed True. Which is exactly the reason while as long as it is humanly possible, you should [not communicate by sharing memory, but share memory by communicating](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PAAkCSZUG1c&t=2m48s)